# I am building react native app . getitng some error in android build

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, package

I am having issue with my react native app android build having this error message pop up

---

```
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: CMake '3.18.1' was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

and then the build fails if anyone knows this issue  please could help me solve this , im using metro not expo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Open SDK Manager
- Switch to the SDK Tools tab
- Install CMake **(select the version highlighted in your error)**

[image]

Comment: @Mennno i tryed stil same issue do I have to restart

Comment: Yes that might help. What OS are you using?

Comment: @famo which version of cmake did you install? You can click `Show Package Details` checkbox to see which version is your installation using. You can then select the exact version mentioned above.

Comment: @MennoSpijker please edit the answer with small details you answer is correct , then I can rate i mistakenly rates wrongly

Comment: @dev404 tq correct i was using wrong version

Comment: @MennoSpijker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73653500/react-native-app-ios-native-base-issue-in-redux-app once solve this another issue popups if possible please do help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line below **presets** in babel.config.js file.

```
plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
```