# react-native app ios native-base issue in redux app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, ecmascript-6, native-base

Hi guys I am creating react native app using redux, react-native cli and having some issue
when starting app it shows as screen shot , i saw online solution mentioning add as below

```
 <NativeBaseProvider>
       <Example/>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
```

---

the problem is I am using redux so when I use like this another redux issue is popping up.
also another solution i tried to unlink native base and then remove and then install then also problem occurs.can anyone suggest me a solution to figure out whats happening and could please show way to solve ?

[image]

---

when i use NativeBaseProvider i get this error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { NativeBaseProvider, useTheme } from 'native-base'

function AppRedux () {
  // not sure where you are getting this modified value from
  const modified = true
  const { colors } = useTheme()

  return !modified ? ( 
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#000' }} />
  ) : (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: colors.primary }} />
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <Provider store={store}> 
        <AppRedux /> 
      </Provider> 
    </NativeBaseProvider> 
  );
}
```

Official docs for `useTheme` from `native-base` are here: https://docs.nativebase.io/theme

Comment: please check my edited part when i use this I get another error its in 2nd screenshot #Asleepace

Comment: @famo can you show me the code where you export your `<App>` component?

Comment: return !modified ? (
   <View style={{}>
    <Text style={[}> 
     
    </Text>
   </View>
  ) : (
   <NativeBaseProvider>
   <Provider store={store}>
    <Appredux />
   </Provider>
   </NativeBaseProvider>
  ).    #Asleepace

Comment: @famo this should not be a conditional, I'll update my answer with your code

Comment: #Asleepace  for use theme from whre do we import that and also can we use the conditional inside the example  function?

Comment: @famo just updated the example, `useTheme` comes from `native-base` in this case: https://docs.nativebase.io/theme